# Why is the time complexity of summing from 1 to n $O(n^2)$?

Tags: summation, asymptotics

I was just recently introduced to Big-O notation and this confused me.

When summing from 1 to n, why is the time complexity O(n<sup>2</sup>)?

In other words, why is $\sum_{i=1}^n i = 1 + 2 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = O(n^2)$?

[This is a screenshot from the course that shows the above equalities.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42v80.png)

Intuitively, I think it should be O(n) since n is the largest factor and the rest are constants so when added, it seems it should produce O(n).

The following is from a lesson that extracts this idea with comments from the instructor that follow the code:

```
def sum_odd(L):
M = L[:]
total = 0
while M != []:
    if M[0] % 2 == 1:
        total = total + M[0]
    M = M[1:]
return total
```

*"The runtime of the loop depends on the iteration number. The slowest line is line 7.
This line of code takes  n−1  time the first iteration,  n−2  time the second iteration, and so on until the second last iteration where it takes 1 operation to make a list of 1 element and on the last iteration, this makes the empty list, which we can also say takes 1 operation.
The sum total of these number of operations is   O(n<sup>2</sup>).
Hence the runtime is   O(n<sup>2</sup>)  for the entire function since line 7 of the loop is the slowest part of this code."*

Comment: The textbook/course is wrong.  In fact, the computational complexity is $O(1)$, as you merely plug in $n$ into $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.  Your italics description doesn't apply to the basic sum.

Comment: Determining the sum has complexity $O(1)$ since there is a formula immediately giving the desired result.

Comment: If you however actually sum up the numbers , the situation is different.

Comment: @Peter Would the time complexity change if you were to individually sum all the elements, disregarding the formula? Perhaps I am missing some information, I will dig around in the course to see if I can find any information that might help give more context to the question.

Comment: The question is whether you want the complexity of some specific (perhaps awful) algorithm or if you want to know the complexity of the best (known) algorithm to some specific problem.

Comment: Big O notation gives an upper bound. Certainly, if it is $O(n)$, then it is also $O(n^2)$.

Comment: To me, it looks like the complexity of _that_ algorithm that is presented as the pseudo-code is $O(n^2)$. Not of some random algorithm but of that _particular_ algorithm. It is also assuming that `M` is some sort of contiguous-in-memory data structure which will need re-allocation and/or copying if shifted. Not all data structures are like that; e.g. if `M` was a _list_, line $7$ would be constant in terms of time.

Comment: Your difficulty is that you think that $\,n(n+1)/2 = O(n)\,$ which is wrong. Please study the definition of "Big-O" notation carefully.

Comment: A function has no complexity, only algorithms have complexity. The algorithm of summing $1$ to $n$ means actually adding them up. There are $n-1$ numbers to add. The function has a better algorithm, but that doesn't mean the algorithm is $O(1),$ only that $O(n)$ can be improved.

Comment: In any event, a faster function is still $O(n).$

Comment: Also, it makes sense to mention the best possible expression , not one that is far worse. We could of course also use O(exp(exp(exp(n)))) , but noone would do this , if the actual complexity is O(n). Another issue is whether the sum can be considered to be made in constant time (which I would assume) or if the complexity of the summation must also be considered.

Comment: The comments above are misleading. You don’t have to consider an algorithm at all. The question is simply about the growth rate of the function $f(n)=1+2+\dots+n$. This is a function you may encounter in the analysis of algorithms, but there is no algorithm under consideration here.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76609194/781723, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4730477/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = O(n^2)$ is not talking about the complexity of performing the addition, it is saying that the function $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ belongs to the complexity class $O(n^2)$.

We say that $f(n) = O(g(n))$ or $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ if there exists $n_0$ and $M > 0$ such that $f(n) \leq Mg(n)$ whenever $n \geq n_0$. In other words, we can find a fixed scaling factor $M$ so that $f(n)$ is bounded by $Mg(n)$ when $n$ is big enough. For $f(n) = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $g(n) = n^2$, we could take, for example, $n_0 = 1$ and $M = 1$ and notice that:

$$\begin{eqnarray} n^2 - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} & = & \frac{1}{2}(2n^2 - n^2 - n) \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}(n^2 - n) \\
& = & \frac{1}{2}n(n-1) \end{eqnarray}$$

which, for $n \geq 1$, is clearly going to be $\geq 0$, and so we have $g(n) \geq f(n)$ which is enough to prove that $f(n) = O(g(n))$. More generally, you can prove that if $f$ and $g$ are polynomials and $g$ has the same or higher degree than $f$, then $f(n) = O(g(n))$.

The point of showing this is that if you have an algorithm that can be broken into parts of size $1, 2, 3, \ldots, n$ (e.g. an outer loop that runs from $m = 1$ to $n$ and an inner loop that runs from $i = 1$ to $m$), then the total size of those parts is going to be $1 + 2 + \ldots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$, and so the overall time complexity of the algorithm is $O(n^2)$.

The algorithm given is trying to demonstrate one such example. The loop runs $n$ times, and in the $m$th iteration the list $M$ is of length $n - m + 1$ (i.e. it starts at length $n$, then becomes length $n - 1$, and so on until it's of length 1). Then in the $m$th iteration the operation $M = M[1:]$ involves creating a list of length $n - m + 1$ which is taken to be of the same complexity as its size, i.e. it's equivalent to a loop of that number of iterations. So we are running something that involves $n$ operations, then $n-1$, then $n-2$, and so forth. If we ignore the other steps in the loop, that means that the algorithm as a whole has $n + (n-1) + (n-2) + \ldots + 1$ operations, which is equal to $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and hence is $O(n^2)$, and we can show that the other parts only add $O(n)$ extra operations to the whole thing which doesn't change the overall complexity.

Comment: Can I say that $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} = O(n^2)$ (or in other words $\frac{n(n+1)}{2} \in O(n^2)$) since by simplifying we get $\frac{n^2}{2} + \frac{n}{2}$ and we can see that $\frac{n^2}{2}$ is the dominant term?
Is what I stated the logic behind quickly evaluating that it is $O(n^2)$ just by looking at it?
Sorry if this seems obvious, I am very new to Big-O notation.

Comment: Yes. Obviously it has to be proven at some point, but once you can take it as a given you can always drop all of the "slower" functions and multiplicative constants to pick out the complexity class. So like I said in the answer, the class of a polynomial is entirely defined by its highest degree term and once you are comfortable with the notation you should absolutely be able to just look at an expression like $\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$ and immediately see that it's cubic and hence $O(n^3)$.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing functions (such as the function describing the runtime of an algorithm) with algorithms themselves. $O$-notation applies to functions, not algorithms.

When analyzing algorithms, we consider the function $T(n)$ that gives the algorithm's runtime on inputs of size $n$. If $T(n)=1+2+\dots+n$, this might correspond to an algorithm that performs one step, then 2 steps, then 3 steps, ..., then $n$ steps. (It has nothing to do with an algorithm for adding the numbers from $1$ to $n$.) This function grows as a quadratic function of $n$, i.e. $T\in O(n^2)$.

Comment: It seems to me you've got it exactly backwards. $O(n)$ is used to describe an algorithm, not a function, and I have no idea what you mean by " the function describing the runtime of an algorithm." Algorithms describe functions, not the other way around.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) describes the limiting behavior of a function - it's not directly related to algorithms. When it's applied to an algorithm, we're implicitly talking about the function that gives the algorithm's runtime on a given input size.

Comment: Ah, I was thinking you were talking about the function $f(n)=1+2+\cdots+n.$ It might be worth mentioning that you are talking about the execution time function.

Comment: We *are* talking about the function $f(n)=1+2+\dots+n$, and we have $f\in O(n^2)$. This is about $f$ itself, not about algorithms for computing $f$.